# Как подключить другой JS при нажатии на ссылку?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background

Мне необходимо реализовать смену фона сайта при нажатии, например, на ссылку. Сейчас фон сайта прописан в `css`, а этот файл, естественно, подключен к каждой странице сайта.

```
body.f1 {
  background-image: url("/images/fon/43.jpg");    
}
body.f2 {
  background-image: url("/images/fon/20.jpg");  
}
body.f3 {
  background-image: url("/images/fon/225.jpg"); 
}
body.f4 {
  background-image: url("/images/fon/31.jpg");  
}
```

И есть `JS` код, который создаёт условие когда и какой фон ставить:

```
function setNewYearBg() {
  var now = new Date(),
      month = now.getMonth(),
      day = now.getDate(),
      hours = now.getHours(),
      minutes = now.getMinutes(); 
  if( (month == 11 && day >= 25) || (month == 11 && day <= 28 ) ) {    
        if( (hours == 16 && minutes >= 59) || (hours >= 17 && hours <= 23 || hours >= 0 && hours <= 8) || (hours == 9 && minutes <= 03) ) {
            document.body.classList.add('f4');
        }
        else if( (hours == 9 && minutes >= 04) || (hours == 10 && minutes <= 01 ) ) {
            document.body.classList.add('f3');
        }  
        else if( (hours == 10 && minutes >= 02) || (hours >= 11 && hours <= 15) || (hours <= 16 && minutes <= 00 ) ) {
            document.body.classList.add('f1');
        } 
        else if( (hours == 16 && minutes >= 01) || (hours == 16 && minutes <= 58 ) ) {
            document.body.classList.add('f2');
        }
  }
}
setNewYearBg();
```

Понятно, что он не весь, я прислал лишь отрывок. Но суть в том, что мне необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку, к примеру, "Сменить фон", использовался другой `JS` и `CSS` файл на этом сайте.

Насколько я понимаю, необходимо использовать:

```
localStorage.getItem('label');

localStorage.setItem('label', 'value');
```

чтобы сохранить выбор пользователя. Но как всё это реализовать, я пока представляю очень смутно.

Comment: Картинку менять?

Comment: проблема уже решена, спасибо)

Comment: закройте вопрос или р ап ищите решение

Comment: знать бы как его закрыть..

Comment: нужно 250 репутации. Напишите тогда ответ

Comment: Я не нашёл его, но пошёл по-другому пути, поэтому это не совсем ответ на эту тему.